# Integration by parts with Dirac Delta function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

I am having some hard time trying to understand the following "heuristic" integral, involving integration by parts with the Dirac's Delta. We start with the following relation
$$
f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(a)\delta(x-a)\,\mathrm da .\tag{1}
$$
which is my starting point. I found in a book the following derivation at the "heuristic" level, without a single word of explanation, which I found obscure. If we consider $f(x) = x^2$, then integrating by parts

$$
x^2 = \int_0^{\infty} a^2\delta(a - x)\,\mathrm da = [-a^2 \mathbf 1_{x>a}]^{\infty}_0 + \int_0^{\infty} 2a \mathbf 1_{x>a}\,\mathrm da .\tag{2}
$$
Where the function $\mathbf 1_{x>a}$ is defined to be 1 for $a<x$ and 0 otherwise.

There are several things unclear to me in this "heuristic" approach:

1. Why in the first integral he passes from and integral defined in $(-\infty, +\infty)$ to an integral over $(0, \infty)$?
2. Apparently the "antiderivative" of the Delta function is here claimed to be the Heaviside function "in reverse", that is it is equal to one from $-\infty$ to $x$ and zero from $x$ to $\infty$, rather than the usual Heaviside function, which is equal to one from $x$ to $\infty$ and zero before. Why?

Every help to clarify is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 0). The derivation of what? The last equation still is heuristic at best.

Comment: 1). Do you know the definition of the delta-function? 2). Not the derivative but antiderivative. And note that you have $\delta(a-x)$ not $\delta(x-a)$

Comment: Comment to the post (v4): The first equality in eq. (2) is not correct if $x<0$.

Comment: Derivation in the sense of "set of steps". I have edited the antiderivative word. However, I don't understand the rest of your comment. I see that I have $\delta(a-x)$ rather than $\delta(x-a)$, and by the way the intrgration endpoints also are different, but I have just taken this from a book, for which I need some clarification.  In other words: does what I wrote make sense, at some "heuristic" level? Why? How should I interpret it?

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, but I think from the context it can be assumed that you can take only $x>0$. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Hints: That extra assumption more or less answers the first subquestion. The second subquestion follows by carefully tracing a sign.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. My problem is that this is the first time that I see such an "integration" carried out and I have absolutely no idea why it is done like that. I am not a physicist, and I am not used to this "heuristic" lines of arguments to work out integrals. So I would appreciate if someone can explain me what is going on here, which from a rigorous point of view does not make any sense.

Comment: If your problem is what I think it is then it can be simply solved "heuristically" if you observe in equation 1 that you could pick any value of $f(a)$ and after performing the integral over the Dirac delta fn as specified it will provide you with $f(x)$. Basically the Dirac delta, $\delta(x-a)$ is infinite at $x=a$ and zero elsewhere... integrating over all space will send all $x\to a$ in a simplistic manner. I always think of the infinite spike when thinking of these functions.

Comment: If $x>a$ think about 1) where this "spike" might lie with respect to zero 2) odd and even integrals and the tricks you can use for them and 3) how you can enforce $x>a$

Comment: I suggest using f(a) = a , and since the integral is symmetrical from -00 to +00, it should be the same as (a^2... ) integrated  from 0 to +00 (first part of (2)).  Also the - sign comes out of reversing the order of (x - a) to (a - x).  I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you write down an answer? That would help to increase the discussion. There are too many comments and no answers yet.

Comment: If you swap x and a in the first equation, things may be more clear.  This is just nomenclature, but then eq (1) will correspond to a common definition of the Dirac Delta (aka Delta function).